# What do Fourier Transforms actually do?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, complex-integration

I will illustrate this with a simple example:

> Consider the exponential decay function $$f(t)=\begin{cases}
>  0  &
>  \ t\lt 0 , \\ A e^{-\lambda t} & \ t\ge 0 \end{cases}$$
>   Where $\lambda \gt 0$ and $A$ is a constant.

Using the formula for the Fourier transform of $f(t)$: 
$$\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{0}0e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\lambda+i\omega \right)t}\mathrm{d}t$$ 
                                                                                                                                $$=0 + \frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{e^{-\left(\lambda+i\omega \right)t}}{\lambda + i \omega}\right]_{t=0}^{\infty}=\color{purple}{\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\lambda+i\omega )}}$$

So, I started with an exponential decay function $f(t)=A e^{-\lambda t}$ and now I have $$\color{purple}{\frac{A}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\lambda+i\omega )}}$$ What exactly does this expression marked purple mean? Or put slightly differently, what does it represent? What did the Fourier transform do to $f(t)$? Basically, what I'm saying is that I have absolutely no idea what the Fourier transform has achieved.

Could someone please spell this out to me in simple English so that I can get a 'feel' for what's going on?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Basically, the Fourier transform at $\omega$ is the "coefficient" of $e^{i \omega t}$ in a "sum" of complex exponentials of various frequences which "add up" to $f$. Except that all these sums are integrals, and there is a normalization constant floating around. One way to tie this back to sums is to work out how the Fourier *series* on $[-M,M]$ in a sense converge to the Fourier transform as $M \to \infty$.

Comment: Using the language of linear systems, if I have a linear, time-invariant system which has output response $f(t)$ to an idealized "impulse" input, then the response of the same system to a complex exponential $e^{i\omega t}$ is $\mathcal{F}(\omega)e^{i\omega t}$, in other words, the output is a complex exponential with the same frequency, and with amplitude $|\mathcal{F}(\omega)|$ and phase shift $\text{arg}\mathcal{F}(\omega)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are expanding a function $f$ in a basis for which differentiation $\frac{d}{dx}$ is diagonalized. That's why the Fourier transform is so useful for studying differential equations. That normalized basis is $e_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{isx}$, and $e_s$ is an eigenfunction of differentiation with eigenvalue $is$, which gives you a diagonalization:
$$
                   \frac{d}{dx}e_{s} = ise_{s},\;\;\; -\infty < s < \infty.
$$
The eigenvalues are real if you look at $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ instead as the fundamental operator; this operator is selfadjoint, and $\{ e_{s}(x)\}_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}$ is a type of basis that diagonalizes $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ and has real eigenvalues.

If you look at the standard basis vectors $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{N}$ for $\mathbb{C}^{N}$ (same as $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ but you allow complex entries,) then you can expand $f \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ along this basis with dot products
$$
                 f = \sum_{n=1}^{N}(f,e_n)e_n
$$
The coefficient of $e_n$ is the complex dot product $(f,e_n)$. The Fourier transform looks like a "continuous" (i.e., integral sum) of this type:
$$
                 f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e_s)e_s ds.
$$
The coefficient of $e_s$ is
$$
       (f,e_s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\overline{e_s(t)}dt = \hat{f}(s).
$$
So,
$$
                   f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)e_{s}(x)ds.
$$
This basis diagonalizes $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$, which makes it appear that differentiation is transformed to multiplication:
$$
               \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)se_{s}(x)ds.
$$
This is the historical view of the Fourier transform and is basically how Fourier saw it.

Comment: Thank you for you're excellent answer. I'm still a little confused; what is meant by $\cfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is diagonalized? I am only familiar with diagonalization in relation to matrices. And what is normalized basis please?

Comment: @BLAZE : You diagonalize a Hermitian matrix $A$ by finding an orthonormal basis $\{ e_{\lambda_n} \}_{n=1}^{N}$ of eigenvectors, i.e., $Ae_{\lambda_n} =\lambda_n e_{\lambda_n}$. That's essentially what is going on with the Fourier transform, except that you have infinitely many eigenvectors, one for each real number $s$. $L=\frac{d}{dx}$ is a linear operator on functions, meaning $L(\alpha f+ \beta g)=\alpha Lf + \beta Lg$.

Comment: @BLAZE : You're welcome.

Comment: @BLAZE (also to TrialAndError, who will get a notification anyway): there is one "hole" in the analogy which has not been pointed out. Specifically, in the discrete (finite or countable) situation, we really write $x=\sum_n \frac{(x,e_n)}{(e_n,e_n)} e_n$. We choose $e_n$ to be unit, so this is really just introducing a factor of $1$ into what is written above. But in the continuous situation, in fact the "basis elements" have infinite $L^2$ norm, so it is impossible to choose them to be unit. So there is some subtlety floating around in relating the sum and the integral to one another.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing this out, that means a lot. I'm sure that TrialAndError will understand and adjust his working accordingly. Regards.

Comment: @Ian : They have have  a normalization factor, and it is the one that I stated: $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. And, by the way, this analogy works for all of the problems arising out of Fourier's separation of variables method for solving differential equations. Finding the factor is tricky; Fourier did it by taking a limit of discrete sums as the length of the interval was allowed to tend to $\infty$. For more general cases, you can get discrete terms that have to be added in with the continuous expansions, too. The $e_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{isx}$ given here is correct.

Comment: @BLAZE : I posted a comment. The normalization $e_{s}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{isx}$ that I gave in the problem is the correct one; nothing needs to be adjusted. Ian may have missed that in the first paragraph.

Comment: @BLAZE (and again TrialAndError) Sorry if my comment suggested that the answer above was actually incorrect, because it is not. (The actual normalization of the Fourier transform is of little consequence, one merely has to insert the appropriate normalization constant into the inverse Fourier transform in whatever convention one uses. I can think of three conventions in active use off the top of my head.) My point was that the division by the squared $L^2$ norm of the basis elements is lost in the continuum limit.

Comment: @TrialAndError Okay, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Roughly speaking, this "division by infinity" lives on in the "multiplication by the infinitesimal $dx$".

Comment: @Ian : Yes, it is possible to take limits because $\int_{s-\epsilon}^{s+\epsilon}e_{s'}(x)ds'$ is an actual square-integrable vector that is an approximate eigenvector of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ with approximate eigenvalue $s$. The correct normalization is a limiting case of the normalization for this actual vector. This, too, is a general principle that works in rather general cases.

Comment: @TrialAndError Let me try to explain, because we seem to be talking past each other. Intuitively, you want to write down $f=\sum_n \frac{(f,e^M_n)}{(e^M_n,e^M_n)} e^M_n$, where $e^M_n$ are appropriate sinusoidal basis functions for $L^2([-M,M])$. Then you want to send $M \to \infty$. But this limit does not make termwise sense, because $(e^M_n,e^M_n)$ blows up. So instead of passing to the limit termwise, we pay attention to the details: $e^M_n(x)=e^{2 \pi inx/M}$. Also $(e^M_n,e^M_n)=M$. (I may be missing some constants that don't depend on $f$.)

Comment: So what you have is more or less a Riemann sum for the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of $f$. So the division by the squared $L^2$ norm of the basis elements is important in connecting the Fourier series to the Fourier transform, even though it no longer actually appears explicitly in the formula for the Fourier transform.

Comment: @Ian : That's right. Physicists like to work with these "wave packets" $\int_{s-\epsilon}^{s+\epsilon}e_{s}(x)ds$ whose sums are $L^{2}$ because of interference. And there is a general principle at work that makes this applicable when dealing with general symmetric 2nd order differential operators $Lf = -(pf')'+qf$, for example. Even when the eigenfunctions are not $L^{2}$, summing over small intervals of eigenvalue parameters gives you something that is $L^{2}$. So the process of normalization, and transforming/inverse transforming works in a more general context.