# What is meant by integral transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

what is the actual meaning of integral transform? I studied about laplace transform and fourier transform, but do not get an idea about how it be used in applications or what is the meaning of such operations?

Comment: I had the exact same problem so I asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455285/what-do-fourier-transforms-actually-do) and it helped me. It may help you as well.

Comment: @BLAZE - since you found TrialAndError's post so helpful, why did you never mark it as the answer?

Comment: @Paul Good question, the answer is because I forgot, I know it's bad of me. I accepted it now though :)